# OnPost() not hitting .NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Hi I'm trying to make a Razor page with a simple form that add the new element into a list, but the `OnPost()` method is never calling. I have a breakpoint on the first line of the method and it never hits, but in the `OnGet()` it works.

This is my `OnPost()` method:

```
 public void OnPost()
        {
            newDocument = Int32.Parse(Request.Form[nameof(newDocument)]);
            newAge = Int32.Parse(Request.Form[nameof(newAge)]);
            newTriage = (Triage)Int32.Parse(Request.Form[nameof(newTriage)]);
            newName = Request.Form[nameof(newName)];
            newGender = Request.Form[nameof(newGender)];
            newSymptoms = Request.Form[nameof(newSymptoms)];

            var newPatient = new Patient
            {
                Document = newDocument,
                Name = newName,
                Age = newAge,
                Gender = newGender,
                Triage = newTriage,
                Symptoms = newSymptoms
            };
            patients.Add(newPatient);
            OrderPatients();
        }
```

And the razor page have this form:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="patientDoc">Documento</label>
        <input asp-for="newDocument" type="number" class="form-control" id="patientDoc" placeholder="ingrese documento">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="patientName">Nombre</label>
        <input asp-for="newName" type="text" class="form-control" id="patientName" placeholder="Nombre">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="patientAge">Edad</label>
        <input asp-for="newAge" type="number" class="form-control" id="patientAge" placeholder="Edad">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="patientGender">Género</label>
        <input asp-for="newGender" type="text" class="form-control" id="patientGender" placeholder="Género">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="patientTri">Prioridad</label>
        <select asp-for="newTriage" class="form-control" id="patientTri">
            @foreach (Triage tri in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Triage)))
            {
                <option>@tri</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="patientSymp">Sintomas</label>
        <input asp-for="newSymptoms" type="text" class="form-control" id="patientSymp" placeholder="Sintomas">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I have read that you have to put this line `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` at the beginning of the page, but I did it and still the OnPost doesn't hit.
Anyone knows what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default method type for `form` is `GET`, so it hits your `OnGet` handler because you didn't specify the method. Change `<form>` to `<form method="post">` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Forget it. I just had to add the `method="form"` at the beginning of the form like this:

```
<form method="post">
. . .
</form>
```

Gonna leave this around here for another newbie like me who might need it.